# Why isn't terminal locating my Ruby file? (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, path

I'm as much of a beginner as one can be. I'm working through *The Well Grounded Rubyist*. I've installed Ruby using rbenv/homebrew, I'm using the same version (2.5.1) as the book does, but I can't get my first ruby program named c2f.rb to work.

**I'm at my wits end here and would appreciate any help figuring out how I can get my terminal to run this program. Thank you!**

I believe there is something messed up with my PATH but I don't know how to fix it. When I view my path using `echo $PATH` my terminal returns:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I have c2f.rb saved in a folder named rubycode, which is within my User folder. When I run `$ ruby c2f.rb` the terminal returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- c2f.rb (LoadError)
```

When I run it within irb, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (undefined local variable or method `c2f' for main:Object)
```

Comment: Have you used `cd` to navigate to the correct folder that the script is located in before trying to execute it with ruby? What do you mean "When I run it within irb" - how are you trying to run it in irb?

Comment: Using cd worked, thank you! 

Do I need to `cd` to rubycode every time I want to run a file located there? By run with irb I mean from terminal I typed `irb` then tried to run the code. Can I run my file from within irb, or does it always have to be outside of it?

Comment: Usually, to run a file you would either navigate to that directory using `cd` or alternatively refer to it by its absolute path. In terms of running your file from IRB, yes you certainly can using [`require`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require), [`require_relative`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require_relative), or [`load`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/load) (or, as a last resort, copy-pasting). I would recommend reading up a little more on those commands.

Comment: Note that `require` and `require_relative` don't reload the file if you've already required it, so that's why when I'm writing code I usually use `load` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made my day with this help. I was ready to throw the computer out the window.

Answer (score -1):

Computers are very good at finding things. So, in 99.99% of cases when a computer tells you that it can't find something, the reason is that the thing *really* is not there.

So, the *very* first steps you should check are:

1. Does there *actually* exist a file named `c2f.rb` in the current working directory?
2. If yes, make sure that it is *really* named `c2f.rb` and not, for example, `c2f.rb` (space at the beginning) or `c2f.rb` (space at the end) or `ϲ2f.rb` (with a Unicode [U+03F2 GREEK LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL (`ϲ`)](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=03F2) instead of the Unicode [U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C (`c`)](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0063)) or something with a zero-width space, zero-width joiner, zero-width non-joiner or anything similar in the middle.